# Combine LAZY load and @JoinColumnOrFormula

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

folks!
I have entity A and this entity has a relationship @ManyToOne wit entity B. Mapping goes as follows:

```java
@Entity
class A {
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'SOME_VALUE'", referencedColumnName = "type"))
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "name::varchar", referencedColumnName = "code", nullable = false))
    private B name;
}
```

It seems like Hibernate loads this entity every time. Is there a way to only fetch only its id?

Comment: Add fetch type to lazy `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
 @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=@JoinColumn(name="custId", referencedColumnName ="id") ),
 @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="1",referencedColumnName = "active"))
})
Customer customer;
`

Comment: @ArunDuraisamy this approach won't work in the current context.

Comment: can you elaborate your question more.

Comment: @ArunDuraisamy >> Please to clarify what exactly clarification do you need to help me to resolve this question. The problem is straightforward. I have an entity and this entity has a relationship to a foreign entity. I need somehow to be able to search by foreign entity attributes. But as a result, return this entity with lazy fields. (Not fetch all foreign entity attributes. )

Comment: Once we query with foreign entity fields, objects will be loaded even though we mapped relation as FetchType.Lazy. 
1. Either think on Mapping a Hibernate Query to a Custom Class so that only required fields can return 
2. try with Entity Graph feature

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the ID, you should not use class B type in the entity, since this tells Hibernate to always fetch the entity when you do getName();

```
@Entity
class A {
    private String name;
}
```

is this not working?

Comment: Yeah, but the problem if I will make the entity in such way. I won't be able to search by foreign entity fields.It is required for my task. So, I need somehow to be able to search by foreign entity attributes and I need to return the entity lazy.